# Apache re-write URL

Tags: apache-2.2

Is there any way to take a user's website request that looks like:

```
prod.site1.com/?APP_ID=123
```

But have it appear to the website as:

```
prod.webapp.com/?APP_ID=123
```

While keeping:

```
prod.site1.com/?APP_ID=123
```

in the user's address bar?

Comment: Please consider a more descriptive title than "how can I do that". :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to configure VirtualHost for prod.webapp.com and VirtualHost for prod.site1.com. And in the prod.site1.com configuration do reverse proxy to prod.webapp.com.

Useful howto is here: http://www.apachetutor.org/admin/reverseproxies